# Difference between function and operator

Tags: r

I have been defined a bind function ,

```
b <- function(f,...) function(x) f(x, ...)
```

so I can do things like (this is a fake example)

```
d = data.frame(x=c(1,2,1), y=c(10, 20, 5))
ddply(d, ~x, b(transform, y=sum(y)))
```

instead of

```
ddply(d, ~x, function (df) { transform(df, y=sum(y)) }
```

Now, I'm trying to define an operator

```
'%b%' <- function(x,...) b(x,...)
```

and try

```
ddply(d, ~x, transform %b% (z=y*10)))
```

It doesn't work. What is the difference ?

When I do

```
> b(transform, y=y/sum(y))(d)
x         y c.1..2..1.
1 1 0.2857143          1
2 2 0.5714286          2
3 1 0.1428571          1
```

That works, but

```
> transform %b% (y=y/sum(y))(d)
Error in transform %b% (y = y/sum(y))(d) : object 'y' not found
```

I understand, there is a 'capture' difference, what can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your example work, you need to match the function argument to an existing function, using `match.fun()`:

```
`%b%` <- function(x,...) match.fun(b)(x,...)
ddply(d, ~x, transform %b% (z=y*10))

  x  y
1 1 10
2 1  5
3 2 20
```

It will also be safer if you use `match.fun()` in your first definition of `f`:

```
b <- function(f, ...) function(x) match.fun(f)(x, ...)
ddply(d, ~x, b(transform, y=sum(y)))
  x  y
1 1 10
2 1  5
3 2 20
```

---

Having answered your question, I now have to point out that I don't understand why you want to do this, since the `plyr` functions like `ddply` as well as the base R `apply` functions already do this.

So, I would write your original example simply like this:

```
ddply(d, ~x, transform, y=sum(y))
  x  y
1 1 15
2 1 15
3 2 20

ddply(d, ~x, transform, y=y/sum(y))
  x         y
1 1 0.6666667
2 1 0.3333333
3 2 1.0000000
```

---

*Edit*:

I had another look at your question. You simply made a syntax error in your function definition. This works perfectly fine with an infix operator:

```
'%b%' <- function(f,...) function(x) f(x, ...)
ddply(d, ~x, transform %b% (z=y*10))
  x  y
1 1 10
2 1  5
3 2 20
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize ddply and apply where working like that and thank you for telling me that. I'm still interested about the answer anyway as my example was just a straight forward one to illustrate the questioni.

Comment: However that doesn't explain me why it works with a function and not with an operator.

Comment: @mb14 It actually does. It just seems you made a syntax error in your infix operator definition. Answer edited.